# Using sql, how can I simultaneously count the filtered and unfiltered occurrences of an attribute?

Tags: sql

So this is probably a simple question, but here goes. I have some filtered data that get via a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_id, count(*) as filtered_count 
FROM my_table
WHERE attribute LIKE '%filter%'
GROUP BY account_id
ORDER BY account_id
```

This gives me an output table with two columns.

I'd like to add a third column,

```
count(*) as total_count
```

that counts the total number of occurrences of each account_id in the entire table (ignoring the filter).

How can I write the query for this three column table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a case expression inside the count function, then remove your where clause:

```
SELECT account_id, 
        count(case when attribute LIKE '%filter%' then 1 end) as filtered_count,
        count(*) as total_count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY account_id
ORDER BY account_id;
```

Using `DISTINCT` although not actually harmful to your query, was redundant due to the grouping, so I have removed it.

Comment: What if I only want to display the entries with a filtered count not equal to 0? Is the best way to just select from this new table I now have?

Comment: Then use `HAVING` to filter this --> `HAVING count(case when attribute LIKE '%filter%' then 1 end) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a case statement for counting with your filter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_id, 
count(case when attribute LIKE '%filter%' then 1 else null end) as filtered_count,
count (*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY account_id
ORDER BY account_id
```